# Send message to specific text channel by name not ID in a Python Discord Bot

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

Is there an equivalent command to client.get_channel('ID') that allows you to send the message to a specifically named text channel.

My project is a report system that will print the reports in a staff chat where all staff can see. I want this to work across multiple servers so using an ID is not an option because all servers have different channel ID's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`discord.utils.get`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.utils.get) to iterate through [`server.channels`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Server.channels) and find the channel with a particular name:

```
import discord
from discord.utils import get

async def report(server, name, *args, **kwargs):
    channel = get(server.channels, name=name, type=discord.ChannelType.text)
    await bot.send_message(channel, *args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: My program doesn't seem to like 'server.channels' How do I get around that?

Comment: @BenjaminJones What error are you seeing?  If you're using [tag:discord.py-rewrite], `server` will be `guild` instead.

Comment: Not using the rewrite. Don’t have access to my PC as have just gone to bed. It was saying that it didn’t recognise ‘server’. I’ll be on my PC again tomorrow and will send over more details.

Comment: You may have to resolve it through `message.server` or `ctx.message.server`, depending on the context you're using this in.

Comment: Unfortunatly that doesn't seem to be working for me. When using `message.server` I get a large error that ends with "TypeError: 'Server' object is not iterable"
Any Ideas?

Comment: Are you trying to `get(message.server` or `get(message.server.channels`?  You shouldn't be trying to iterate over the server.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179642/discussion-between-benjamin-jones-and-patrick-haugh).